# Using VML, is it possible to set text color and position?

Tags: css, templates, newsletter, vml, textcolor

I am designing a newsletter template with a VML element in it, and I am wondering if it is possible to set text inside a TextBox element to different colors as well as set the position of said text?

I am currently using the following VML :

```
<v:textbox inset="0px,30px,0px,0px" style="v-text-anchor:bottom; color:white;position:absolute;bottom:0px;">
```

The text has moved down, but I need it to go lower and the color attribute doesn't seem to take at all (not totally surprised, I didn't really expect css to work there). Does anyone who has experience with VML know something I could do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's the documentation from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#text)

```html
<font color="hex-color-here">Text Here</font>
```

(inside the textbox) works.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `<span>` or `<font>` tag inside the textbox and add your CSS to that.

Comment: Would that actually render in Outlook though? The only reason VML is in there is so the template will be viewed correctly when looked at in Outlook.

Comment: It should. I've never used textbox, but it works for fill. as used in backgrounds.cm

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to have any effect. I think the issue is that Outlook doesn't render most CSS, and VML has a **few** styles that work with it but I don't think the "color:" attribute is one of them.